# Very many dummy variables in R 2.15.2 -- error solved by upgrading R to 3.0.1?

Tags: r, bigdata

I've got a model that looks (in part) like this:  `m = lm(log(y)~ID+x)`, which give me the following error:

```
Error in rep.int(c(1, numeric(n)), n - 1L) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

`y` is 500,000 long, and `ID` is a factor with 60,000 levels.  500Kx60K >2^31, which is R's object size limit.

**If I upgrade to the new R (3.0.1), will this problem be solved?**  or does the error message come from somewhere else?  (I'm not entirely clear on how to upgrade R from Ubuntu 13.04, which I use.)

EDIT:  The factor is in fact not meant to be interpretable. The factor is akin to a de-meaning in a "fixed-effects" regression. The other components of the model (`x`) are of interest. The question is: what is the response of y to a change in x, controlling for unobservable time-invariant heterogeneity? The dataset is a panel.  I should add that I am not using `plm` because the main model of interest will be a random coefficients model or a generalized additive model. I'd prefer not to have to manually fix the standard errors after a manual de-meaning, and I'd like to get a fitted model object to use in a monte-carlo analysis.

Comment: I think you'll be much better off converting your factor into something with many, many fewer levels. A variable like that will almost never be useful. Even if you manage to get the model to run, the results won't be meaningful or informative.

Comment: The factor is in fact not meant to be interpretable.  The factor is akin to a de-meaning in a "fixed-effects" regression.  The other components of the model (not listed here because they aren't relevant to to problem) are of interest.  The question is: what is the response of `y` to a change in `x`, controlling for unobservable time-invariant heterogeneity?  The dataset is a panel.  To understand these sorts of models, consult an econometrics text.

Comment: I should add that I am not using `plm` because the main model of interest will be a random coefficients model or a generalized additive model.  I'd prefer not to have to manually fix the standard errors after a manual de-meaning, and I'd like to get a fitted model object to use in a monte-carlo analysis.  And yes, I am working on a cluster computer that can handle that kind of memory.

Comment: have you tried sparse model matrices?  There was a recent question on SO saying that they didn't work (as well as I would have expected, at least), but it would seem worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the limited question, yes, that number of levels is less than the new limit on the size of vectors which is the mantissa size (or to use [the word preferred by the IEEE Committee, "significand"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard))  for numeric class (64-bit floating point) variables:

```
>  500000*60000 > 2^32
[1] TRUE
> 500000*60000 > 2^52
[1] FALSE
```

To address the larger question. I doubt upgrading would solve that problem. That is not the error message I would have expected for an overflow on assignment to a vector caused by an over-sized index:

```
a <- numeric(10)
> a[ 2^56] <- 0
Error in a[2^56] <- 0 : vector is too large
```

... so I'm guessing your guess about the source of the error is incorrect. You have logs in your model and getting negative values after logged variables is to be expected.